# How to show div on hovering image?

Tags: html, css

I have some nested div and in one i got an image.
If the user hovers the image it should display another span (in the same wrapper).

html source:

```
<div class="columns one-third"> 
<a href="#">
<img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2013/088/7/2/transformers_gold_icon_by_slamiticon-d5z7dqs.png" alt="Jack Sparrow" width="250px">
</a>
<div class="team-name"><h5>Jack Sparrow</h5><span></span></div>
<div class="team-about"><p><span class="slug">Chief Executive Officer / CEO</span><span class="number">#97</span></p></div>
```

css source:

```
div>a>img {
filter: url(/filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

div>a>img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    display:block;
}

div.team-about .slug{
    float:left;
}

div.team-about .number{
    float:right;
    margin: -10px 10px auto;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: none;
}
```

I prepared a jsfiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/mnx8agy0/

hovering the image it should load the number span.

Any idea on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mnx8agy0/1/

```
div > a:hover ~ .team-about .number {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the hover to the container div:

```
div.one-third:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This triggers when hover the div, not the image.

Answer (score -1):

```
.team-about{display:none;}
div > a:hover + .team-about{display:block;}
```

It's quite easy to use JavaScript instead.

Comment: This won't work because `.team-about` is not a (grand-)child of `div > a`.