# Show div in image hover (css)

Tags: css, hover

I'm using this code to show some text when the mouse enter into the image div:

```
col-1-1.mydiv-image:hover +.mydiv-title h3 {
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
opacity:1;
display:block;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

When the mouse is over the image it's ok, but when the mouse is hover the image and also over the tite (h3) the opacity return to 0 :(

Here is a short video to better understand :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B554jP6zQzw-am83N2JHZnlWVWs/view

Comment: Can you please post your html structure?

Comment: These will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164320/css-hover-image-show-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339182/css-hover-on-image-load-a-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285403/how-to-show-div-on-hovering-image

Comment: Probably what is happening is you are saying when you hover over the image, show .mydiv-title h3. When your mouse moves over to .mydiv-title, it is no longer "hovering" on the image, so it no longer applies the style. That's my guess at what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Kyle Hawk commented. You are only telling the `.mydiv-title h3` to show when you hover over the image. When the mouse is over the `.mydiv-title h3` the mouse is no longer on top of the image, it is now on top of the `h3`.

To fix this all you have to do is add the `.mydiv-title h3:hover` to your code.

```
col-1-1.mydiv-image:hover + .mydiv-title h3,
.mydiv-title h3:hover {
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
    opacity:1;
    display:block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```